# Installing package into Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, conda

I have downloaded the package wquantiles, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wquantiles, and I have installed it into anaconda using `pip install wquantiles`.  When I type in the cmd `conda list` it shows up as installed, but when I try to import it into spyder as `import wquantiles` it says `No module named wquantiles`.  Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

run this in your terminal :

```
conda install -c siboles wquantiles
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `wquantiles` with `pip install wquantiles` like you did, and doing `import wquantiles` in python gave me the same error. Looking at the installation path (for me in Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`) did not show me a `wquantiles` directory, only `wquantiles-0.3.egg-info/` and a new file: `weighted.py`. This latest file contains the function (also see the [github page](https://github.com/nudomarinero/wquantiles/blob/master/weighted.py)).

So the **solution** is to:

```
import weighted
```

then you can run for example:

```
weighted.median(data,weights)
```

Comment: I tried that too, and it still says no module named weighted, when I browse to where the `.egg-info/`  path is there is no .py files just some txt files

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. Since version 0.5, the package wquantiles can be imported with a more intuitive:

```
import wquantiles
```

or:

```
from wquantiles import median, quantile
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

Run: `pip3 install wquantiles`

```py
import wquantiles
```

Add this line ^^ in top of your file